# Updating my very first install of Drupal

Tags: updating

I'm getting emails to update my very first install. How should I go about updating? Should I download the file and drag and drop using Filezilla, or should I use command prompt on my server? http://drupal.org/project/drush/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can use Drush, do. It makes life very easy. If memory serves it's as simple as issuing a `drush up drupal` command, and following the prompts.

If you can't use Drush then copying the core Drupal files over the top of the old ones is the way to go, but make sure you don't replace the `/sites` folder. On most production servers the `/.htaccess` file will also have been modified so make sure you don't overwrite it if there have been changes made.

Either way, make sure you take a backup of the code and database before upgrading so you can easily rollback if something goes wrong.

You may find the [Update your Drupal site from one minor 7.x version to another minor 7.x version](http://drupal.org/node/1223018) page a particularly useful read before getting started.

Also, as Kalabro points out in the comments, never run an update on a production server without having tested it on your dev/staging environment first.

Comment: And one more link: [Use test sites](http://drupal.org/node/22282)